# AWS Billing "Tax Address" by SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-billing

I don't find any AWS API call to extract "Tax Address" of the AWS account.
In AWS console it appears under https://console.aws.amazon.com/billing/home?region=us-east-1#/tax
The screenshot shows how it exactly looks like.
I want to extract this information via aws-cli or any other SDK, java, python or whatever.

[image: https://console.aws.amazon.com/billing/home?region=us-east-1#/tax]

Comment: I agree. This information does not appear to be available via an API. The closest match would be for AWS Organizations, but it does not contain the information you seek.

Comment: Thank you @JohnRotenstein. Is it the final official answer?

Comment: I cannot represent a "final official answer". I am merely stating that I failed to find an applicable API call. I searched through IAM and AWS Organizations API calls.